# Using Dropdown Field with Inline Form In Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use a dropdown in an inline form. This is the code I'm using and it's not styling correctly and the 100% width isn't displaying.

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="claimnumber">Payer</label>
        <select class="form-control">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
        </select>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: You should probably provide your css here since that seems to be what is giving you trouble.

Comment: It's just the standard Bootstrap css

Comment: In that case, nothing is wrong with your markup (see http://jsfiddle.net/zgd5H/ with your markup using http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css external resource).  Check to see that you have the css file properly referenced in your page.

Comment: Could you maybe show a screenshot? Inline form is to make all your inputs on a single line, you seem to have only 1 `select`, why would you need inline for this?